# How to stream audio mp3 file on web

Tags: audio, streaming, audio-streaming

Approx we all know about `gaana.com`, and `saavn.com`, that website stream audio mp3 files to client side but does't allow to users to grab the `audio` files, actually we want to know what technology he used to stream the `audio` mp3 files.

is he using streaming server or or something else ?

Can you describe the technology he is using in steaming the audio files.

Actually we are also creating a web app where `audio` files will be streammed in client side and we also don't want to allow users to download our `mp3` files like `gaana.com` or `saavn.com`.

and we are also curious about if we want to stream our `audio` mp3 files in three different quality the what should i do. Should we convert all the mp3 files in all the three different quality and upload to the server or is any another solution exist for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code your own streaming server then you can use this link

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DeeFuzzer/ it's a python based streaming server, or you can also use ffmpeg or even VLC

Comment: i don't want to write code for server, can u tell us about how `gaana.com` implements such kinds of things.